# Swagger CodeGen Multiple API Endpoints

Tags: swagger-codegen

So after using the Swagger-CodeGen, I was wondering if there was any way to exclude generating the Client Folder (with Configuration, ApiClient, ApiException, etc) since this code seems to be boilerplate and it would be duplicated when I have a multiple endpoints generated with CodeGen.

Besides from manually going to delete the client folder and remapping the namespaces in the generated Api's, is there currently a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip file generation by using the .swagger-codegen-ignore file, which works very similar to .gitignore. Here is an example:

```
# Swagger Codegen Ignore
# Lines beginning with a # are comments

# This should match build.sh located anywhere.
build.sh

# Matches build.sh in the root
/build.sh

# Exclude all recursively
docs/**
```

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#ignore-file-format

Comment: If the client folder is in the ignore list, then the API classes will still be generated thinking the client classes are there causing compilation errors. If I could set the namespace that the API classes think the Client classes belong to this would work. I have already specified a custom namespace for the project using packageName, but am not aware of a configuration setting for the classes in the client folder.